# Find formula of function given relation

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, monotone-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function.

If $f(0)>0$ and $f(x)(f(x)(1-x)+2xf'(x))=1, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ then

show that $f(0)=1$ and $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{e^x-1}{x}}, x \neq 0$. Also show that the function $g=f^2$ is strictly increasing and convex in $\mathbb{R}$ and has the $y=0$-axis horizontal asymptotic in $-\infty$.

I have thought the following:

We have that $(x^2 f(x))'=2xf(x)+x^2 f'(x)$.

So $f(x)(1-x)+2xf'(x)=f(x)(1-x)-(x^2f(x))'-x^2 f'(x)$.

So we find other similar relations in order to get the desired result? Or do we proceed somehow else?

**EDIT** : We get the equation: $f^2(x)-xf^2(x)+2xf(x)f'(x)=1$.

By setting $g=f^2$ we get that $g'(x)+\frac{1-x}{x}g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

How do we solve this?

Comment: Look at the equation verified by $g := f^2$ ;)

Comment: @LL3.14 I applied your hint(see post). How can we continue?

Comment: $g^\prime(x) + \frac{1-x}{x}g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is a first order linear differential equation. Look up methods of how to solve them. There is a general method that isn't too complicated.

Comment: A first way is to multiply the equation by $x$ and remark that you have the derivative of $x g(x)$ appearing. But since you know the solution, you can also just replace $f$ by your solution and remark that it works ... and then say that it is the unique solution up to a constant (at least for $x$ away from zero) by uniqueness theorem. Then find the constant to get the good value at $x=0$.

But you will never suceed in maths if you do not try by yourself and wait for solutions!

Comment: Ok I found the integral factor and found the solution. Could you take a look at me other question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3751113/how-to-we-get-the-inverse-function